# How do I select an HTML attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I added a custom attribute to a Textbox:

```
<asp.TextBox MyCustomAttribute="SomeValue"><asp.TextBox>
```

And I'd like to access that value from inside an `AJAX` success function if possible.

Also note that I've left off any attributes and parameters that aren't relevant to my question.

I'm using `AJAX` inside of a jQuery `change()` function so when users update the value in the textbox it updates the database without posting back and I have that much already working.

Once I'm inside the context of my `change()` function, I set the value of `MyCustomAttribute` to a variable so I can (theoretically) access it from inside the `AJAX` success function:

```
.change(function () {
  var MyCustomAttribute = $(this).attr("MyCustomAttribute");
  $.ajax({
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.d == "SUCCESS") {
        // here I just want to see if I can access the value
        // of MyCustomAttribute so I'm trying to set it to a
        // variable and do an alert()
        var DidItWork = $("input[MyCustomAttribute='" + MyCustomAttribute + "']");
        alert(DidItWork);
  });
});
```

But so far it's not working, I've tried typing my jQuery select for my `DidItWork` variable a few different ways, but instead of displaying `SomeValue` like I was hoping, my alert displays `[object Object]` or `[undefined]`.  I tried it with and without a `.val()` at the end, but that makes the alert display the value that's in the textbox, not the value of `MyCustomAttribute`.

Anyway I'm not sure what part of the syntax I'm getting wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: But your didItWork variable is set to the jQuery object that wraps that DOM node you've chosen. To display the value of myCustomAttribute, you'd console.log(DidItWork.attr("MyCustomAttribute") );

Comment: Is the element in the response? If yes, than it ain't going to fins anything in the document. If you are trying to find the element where you got the attr in the first place, than why are you not using it? You already have a reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-manipulating-element-attributes/), you can use attr() inside of jQuery to manipulate HTML attributes.

You should assign the text box an id and use jQuery to get that element and modify its attributes using attr().

An example line of code is:

```
$('#textBox').attr('MyCustomAttribute', 'SomeNewValue');
```

Comment: It has an ID, but there can potentially be dozens of those textboxes on the page. I'm trying to use MyCustomAttribute as a unique identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try to find asp.TextBox by class like this:

```
<asp.TextBox class="tb" MyCustomAttribute="SomeValue"><asp.TextBox>


.change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    success: function (response) {
      if (response.d == "SUCCESS") {
        var DidItWork = $(".tb").attr("MyCustomAttribute");
        alert(DidItWork);
  });
});
```

Comment: It has a class, but like my reply to Clink123, I can't find the textbox I'm trying to select by class or ID alone, I need MyCustomAttribute to make it unique as there can be dozens of these textboxes on the page